Apache Tomcat 9.0 Maintenance and Security Updates Duration
I am currently using Apache Tomcat 9.0 in our production environment, and I would like to know more about its maintenance and security updates schedule. Specifically:
Until when will Apache Tomcat 9.0 receive maintenance and support?
Will security updates continue to be released for Tomcat 9.0, similar to the ongoing support for Tomcat 10.1?
Understanding this information will help us plan our future upgrade strategy accordingly. Any insights or official references would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
I am currently using Apache Tomcat 9.0 in our production environment, and I would like to know more about its maintenance and security updates schedule. Specifically:
Until when will Apache Tomcat 9.0 receive maintenance and support?
Will security updates continue to be released for Tomcat 9.0, similar to the ongoing support for Tomcat 10.1?
Understanding this information will help us plan our future upgrade strategy accordingly. Any insights or official references would be greatly appreciated.
